# Why tcpdump -dd accepting packet instruction choosese exactly 0x4000 as size?

Tags: packet, bpf

Why tcpdump -dd always use 0x4000 as the size of packet to return in the accepting case? I know it's big enough to return the entire packet. But why exactly that value and not for example 65536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, just search for the value in the source code, in our case [in libpcap](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/libpcap-1.9.0/pcap-int.h#L72-L93) (by the way: it's `0x40000`).

```c
/*
 * Maximum snapshot length.
 *
 * Somewhat arbitrary, but chosen to be:
 *
 *    1) big enough for maximum-size Linux loopback packets (65549)
 *       and some USB packets captured with USBPcap:
 *
 *           http://desowin.org/usbpcap/
 *
 *       (> 131072, < 262144)
 *
 * and
 *
 *    2) small enough not to cause attempts to allocate huge amounts of
 *       memory; some applications might use the snapshot length in a
 *       savefile header to control the size of the buffer they allocate,
 *       so a size of, say, 2^31-1 might not work well.
 *
 * We don't enforce this in pcap_set_snaplen(), but we use it internally.
 */
#define MAXIMUM_SNAPLEN     262144
```